# Find a percentage value in a string using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to isolate the percentage value in a string of text. This should be pretty easy using preg_match, but because the percentage sign is used as an operator in preg_match I can't find any sample code by searching.

```
$string = 'I want to get the 10%  out of this string';
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
$percentage = '10%';
```

My guess is that I'll need something like:

```
$percentage_match = preg_match("/[0-99]%/", $string);
```

I'm sure there is a very quick answer to this, but the solution is evading me!

Comment: how about catching 100%?

Comment: "**the percentage sign is used as an operator in preg_match**" <-- that is simply untrue.  The regex engine does not apply any special meaning to the percent sign.  It will be treated as a string literal without escaping it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (preg_match("/[0-9]+%/", $string, $matches)) {
    $percentage = $matches[0];
    echo $percentage;
}
```

Comment: @Hirad this answer does not need to account for floats or roman numerals or any other invented extention to the OP's requirements.  If you need to match floats before a percentage sign, please look for a page that requires that rule.

Comment: @mickmackusa nowhere in OP's requirements says the number can't be float.

Answer (score 4):

use the regex `/([0-9]{1,2}|100)%/`. The `{1,2}` specifies to match one or two digits. The `|` says to match the pattern *or* the number 100.

`[0-99]` which you had matches *one* character in the range `0-9` or the single digit `9` which is already in your range.

Note: This allows 00, 01, 02, 03...09 to be valid. If you do not want this, use `/([1-9]?[0-9]|100)%/` which forces one digit and an optional second in the range `1-9`

Comment: What about if percent value is not an integer, but e.g. 0.01%? I think the following regexp would be better: /[\d.]+(?=%)/ as it matches numbers that are immediately before %.

Comment: @Marcin Well my recommendation is based on his post and original regex attempt showing integers in the range 0-99. If decimals are possible then he would need to adjust.

Answer (score 3):

Why not `/\d+%/`? Short and sweet.

Answer (score 1):

The regex should be `/[0-9]?[0-9]%/`.

The ranges inside character classes are for 1 character only.

Answer (score 0):

```
$number_of_matches = preg_match("/([0-9]{1,2}|100)%/", $string, $matches);
```

The match will be in the `$matches` array, specifically `$matches[1]`.