# Get number before the percent sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string like that:

```
$string = "Half Board, 10% Off & 100 Euro Star - Save £535";
```

The percentage can be anywhere in the string.

This is what I have, but I don't like the fact that it has a preg_replace AND a loop operation, which are heavy. I'd like a ReGex expression that would do it in one operation.

```
$string = "Half Board, 10% Off & 100 Euro Star - Save £535";
$string_array = explode(" ", $string);
$pattern = '/[^0-9,.]*/'; // non-digits

foreach($string_array as $pc) {

    if(stristr($pc, '%')) {

        $percent = preg_replace($pattern, '', $pc);
        break;
    }
}

echo $percent;
exit;
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I did say I need to pregmatch; expected result = get number right before the % sign. RegEx I was looking for = '/\d+(?=%)/' I think this question is quite legit.

Comment: We expect you to write some code and show us the things you've tried. That way we are sure that you aren't just asking for free code and on the way we might improve the code you've wrote or correct the things where you were wrong. You will learn from it way more than when you get ready made code which sometimes don't even come with explanation.

Comment: For future reference, there's no need to add the solution to your question itself - it will be evident from the accepted answer. :-)

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4799671/2943403 but that question wants to retain the `%` in the match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:
From the code you added to your question, I get the impression your percentages might look like `12.3%` or even `.50%`. In which case, the regex you're looking for is this:

```
if (preg_match_all('/(\d+|\d+[.,]\d{1,2})(?=\s*%)/','some .50% and 5% text with 12.5% random percentages and 123 digits',$matches))
{
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => .50
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 12.5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => .50
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 12.5
    )

)
```

the expression explained:

- `(\d+|\d*[.,]\d{1,2})`: is an OR -> either match digits `\d+`, or `\d*` zero or more digits, followed by a decimal separator (`[.,]`) and 1 or 2 digits (`\d{1,2}`)
- `(?=\s*%)`: only if the afore mentioned group is followed by zero or more spaces and a % sign

---

Using a regular expression, with a positive lookahead, you can get exactly what you want:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\d+(?=%)/', 'Save 20% if you buy 5 iPhone charches (excluding 9% tax)', $matches))
{
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

gives you:

```
array (
    0 => '20',
    1 => '9'
)
```

Which is, I believe, what you are looking for
The regex works like this:

- `\d+` matches at least 1 digit (as many as possible)
- `(?=%)`: provided they are followed by a `%` sign

Because of the lookahead, the `5` isn't matched in the example I gave, because it's followed by a space, not a `%` sign.
If your string might be malformed (have any number of spaces between the digit and the `%` sign) a lookahead can deal with that, too. As ridgerunner pointed out to me, only lookbehinds need to be of fixed size, so:

```
preg_match_all('/\d+(?=\s*%)/', $txt, $matches)
```

The lookahead works like this

- `\s*`: matches zero or more whitespace chars
- `%`: *and* percent sign

Hence, both `123     %` and `123%` fit the pattern, and will match.
A good place to read up on regex's [is regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

---

If *"complex"* regex's (ie with lookaround assertions) aren't your cup of tea (yet, though I strongly suggest learning to use them), you *could* resort to splitting the string:

```
$parts = array_map('trim', explode('%', $string));
$percentages = array();
foreach($parts as $part)
{
    if (preg_match('/\d+$/', $part, $match))
    {//if is required, because the last element of $parts might not end with a number
        $percentages[] = $match[0];
    }
}
```

Here, I simply use the `%` as delimiter, to create an array, and trim each string section (to avoid trailing whitespace), and then procede to check each substring, and match any number that is on the end of that substring:

```
'get 15% discount'
['get 15', 'discount']
/\d+$/, 'get 15' = [15]
```

But that's just an awful lot of work, using a lookahead is just way easier.

Comment: FYI - With PHP/PCRE, lookahead assertions can have variable length. (i.e. `(?=\s*%)` is perfectly valid.) Its the alternatives within _lookbehinds_ that are limited to fixed length.

Comment: @ridgerunner: Right you are, I've edited my answer to reflect that. I recently had some trouble with the fixed-size of lookbehinds, and sort of assumed that lookaheads suffered from the same ailments. Makes sense, though, seeing as they're zero-width, there should be no reason why they can't be of variable length

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the updated answer is not working. It returns [50,50]

Comment: @HiradRoshandel: Just had a look (It's a 6-7y old update). AFAIK, it's still performing as expected: [tried here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e7bf83c6d3397a28a8bfbeabb1646c8f38cd9b77)

Comment: Why not `/\d+(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?(?=\s*%)/` and avoid the unnecessary capture group?  Or if anyone doesn't care for digits before the decimal: `/\d*(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?(?=\s*%)/` e.g. `.50`

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "Half Board, 10% Off & 100 Euro Star - Save £535";
preg_match("|\d+|", $str, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: $str = "Half Board, 10% Off & 100 Euro Star - Save £535"; This string will match the price and numbers, but I only need it to match the percentage. :(

Comment: @User016 lolwut ? You changed the delimiters and the string, that's all. You might test your regexes online at http://regex101.com . I'll also give you a hint: use a lookahead.

Comment: I have checked and tsted it before posting.That will give 10 as output @HamZa

Comment: You're not answering the question, which requires there to be a `%` sign after the number, you're just blindly matching all numbers. Check my answer for a regex _with_ look-ahead

Comment: @User016 Let's take an example `You got 10% discount, a warranty of 5 years`. Your expression will also match `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `split` like

```
$str_arr = split(' ',$str);
$my_str = split('%',$str_arr[1]);
echo $my_str[0];
```

Comment: The percentage can be anywhere in the string.
Not neccessary the 1st position

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$str = "Save 20% on iPhone chargers...";
if (preg_match_all('/\d+(?=%)/', $str, $match))
   print_r($match[0]);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/FLKtE9